# What is the advantage of using imaginary units for time in the Minkowski Space rather than regular euclidian space as Lorentz used?

Tags: special-relativity, metric-tensor, coordinate-systems, complex-numbers, wick-rotation

I do understand that Lorentz transformations became as a rotation of coordinates as of a hyperbolic rotation. But what is its advantage over real vector? What is the new thing that it introduces and what problems does it fix or ease?

Comment: Just a lot of confusion, keep away from the  $i$t formalism in relativity....

Comment: I am writing a paper on the usage of complex numbers on the Minkowski space but since I started it's all confusion for me too.

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/107443/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/121380/2451 and links therein.