# How can we physically determine the metric in SR? How can we physically determine a coordinate system where $g$ is diagonalized?

Tags: special-relativity, spacetime, metric-tensor, symmetry, coordinate-systems

Here I'll use theoretical units with $c=1$. Suppose we are given two coordinate systems $(t, x)$ and $(\tilde{t}, \tilde{x})$, and suppose they are related by $t = \tilde{t} - \tilde{x}/2$ and $x = \tilde{x}$. How can we tell which one has its time axis perpendicular to its spatial axes?

Equivalently, how can I tell that the metric $g$ in the $(t, x)$-coordinates is of the form $g = dt^{2}-dx^{2}$ and not $g = dt^{2} - (3/4)dx^{2} + dt\; dx$?

Is there any sequence of physical experiments I could do to select the "correct coordinate system" where the metric is diagonalized? Equivalently how can I physically deduce the metric in a given coordinate system? Is it even possible to fully determine the metric?

Comment: You cannot ever deduce a coordinate system. The fact that you can’t is the coordinate invariance which characterizes the theories of relativity. You can deduce general facts about your metric. The symmetries of space and those of time constrain the possible forms of your metric.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume we are working in special relativity with $D+1$ dimensional spacetime. Suppose we have an inertial coordinate system $(x^{\mu})$, so objects that don't interact with anything move in uniform motion according to these coordinates. If we can determine another coordinate system where the metric $g$ is known, and if we know how to transform between the old and new coordinate systems, then we can determine $g$ in the original coordinates.

Since the metric is symmetric (i.e. $g_{\mu\nu} = g_{\nu\mu}$), there are
$$ \binom{D+1}{2}+(D+1) = \frac{(D+1)(D+2)}{2} $$
many degrees of freedom for the metric. We can consider the following parts of $g$:

- $g_{00}$
- $g_{ii}$ and $g_{i0}$
- $g_{ij}$ where $i < j$.

The first bullet describes only one component, the second bullet describes $2D$ many components, and the last bullet describes $\binom{D}{2} = D(D-1)/2$ many components. In total, we describe
$$ 1 + 2D + \frac{D(D-1)}{2} = \frac{(D+1)(D+2)}{2} $$
many components, which is exactly the number of degrees of freedom of $g$.
For each component, we will either transform coordinates so that the component is eliminated, or we will set up a system of equations that will allow us to determine the values of components.
We will proceed in three steps.

> **Part 1.** Let $g_{S} = g_{ij}dx^{i}dx^{j}$ be the spatial part of $g$. We will find a new coordinate system in which $g_{S}$ is diagonalized. To do this we will exploit the Lorentz force law as follows. Send a stream of electrons in any direction. By applying an (approximately) uniform magnetic field to the electron beam in various ways, we are able to find/construct spatial axes that are orthogonal to one another according to $g_{S}$. This gives us a new system $(y^{i})$ of coordinates in which
> $$ g_{S} = g'_{11}dy^{1}dy^{1} + \cdots + g'_{DD}dy^{D}dy^{D} $$ for some reals $g'_{11}, \ldots, g'_{DD}$.
>
> By transforming from $(x^{\mu}) = (x^{0}, x^{i})$ to $(y^{\mu}) = (x^{0}, y^{i})$, we obtain $g = g'_{\mu\nu}dy^{\mu}dy^{\nu}$ where $g'_{ij} = 0$ for all $i\ne j$.
> The components $g'_{ij}$ with $i < j$ are determined to be zero.
> This leaves us with the remaining $2D+1$ components to be determined.
>
> **Part 2.** To determine the rest of the coefficients, we proceed as follows. We assume that the two-way speed of light is always $c=1$, but for the sake of generality we won't assume a fixed one-way speed of light in coordinates $(y^{\mu})$.
>
> The one-way speed of light in a direction can be found by sending a light signal from the origin of our coordinates to a clock at a distance $L$ from the origin (according to our coordinates). Then we take
> $$ \frac{L}{(\text{receiver clock at reception}) - (\text{transmitter clock at transmission})}, $$
> and this will be the one-way speed of light according to the $(y^{\mu})$-coordinates. Hence the one-way speed of light in any direction is a known quantity.
>
> For each index $i$ where $1\le i\le D$, we let $c_{+}^{i} > 0$ be the one-way speed of light in direction $+y^{i}$ and let $c_{-}^{i} < 0$ be the (negative of the) one-way speed of light in direction $-y^{i}$. Let $1\le k\le D$ and consider shooting two light beams in the $+y^{k}$ and the $-y^{k}$ directions.
> For light beams going to the $\pm y^{k}$ directions,
> $$ dy^{k}/c_{\pm}^{k} = dy^{0} \qquad\text{ and }\qquad  dy^{i} = 0 \;\text{ for }\; i\ne k. $$
> If $c_{+}^{k}$ is infinite, then any fraction with an infinite denominator is interpreted to equal zero.
> Likewise for $c_{-}^{k}$.
> Knowing that $ds^{2} = 0$ for null geodesics, we find
> \begin{align*}
> 0 &= g'_{\mu\nu}dy^{\mu}dy^{\nu} \\[1.0ex]
> &= g'_{00}dy^{0}dy^{0} + g'_{k0}dy^{0}dy^{k} + g'_{0k}dy^{k}dy^{0} + g'_{kk}dy^{k}dy^{k} \\[1.0ex]
> &= \left[ g'_{00}/(c_{\pm}^{k})^{2} + 2g'_{k0}/c_{\pm}^{k} + g'_{kk} \right] dy^{k}dy^{k}.
> \end{align*}
> Since $dy^{k}$ is nonzero for light beams moving in the $\pm y^{k}$ directions, we obtain
> \begin{align*}
> 0 &= g'_{00}/(c_{+}^{k})^{2} + 2g'_{k0}/c_{+}^{k} + g'_{kk}, \\
> 0 &= g'_{00}/(c_{-}^{k})^{2} + 2g'_{k0}/c_{-}^{k} + g'_{kk}
> \end{align*}
> for $1\le k\le D$.
> This provides $2D$ equations that are linear in the metric components.
>
> **Part 3.** Lastly, consider the time interval from $y^{0} = 0$ to $y^{0} = 1$, and set $g'_{00}$ to be the negative square of the time $T$ elapsed there, so that $g'_{00} = -T^{2}$.

From parts 2 and 3, we obtain $2D+1$ many equations with $2D+1$ components to solve for. Without proof, I claim this is a solvable system of equations, and so all components $g'_{\mu\nu}$ are known in the $(y^{\mu})$-coordinates.

By transforming back to the $(x^{\mu})$-coordinates, we find $g_{\mu\nu}$'s in the original coordinate system, as desired.

Answer (score 1):

I think your questions aren't well-posed since you aren't giving definitions of your coordinates (or are making implicit assumptions).

I will show how radar experiments (in the spirit of the Bondi k-calculus) will define a metric $ds^2=dt^2-dx^2$.

(This is based on my answer https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/508251/148184
to [Minkowski Metric Signature](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/107443/minkowski-metric-signature) .)

[image: robphy-Bondi-a]

*(This is based on a diagram from Bondi's "E=mc2: An Introduction to Relativity" (http://www.worldcat.org/title/emc2-an-introduction-to-relativity/oclc/156217827).
I corrected a typo in the original.*)

After a time $T$ after separation-event-O, Alice sends a signal to Bob.
That signal is received by Bob at an event-Q when his watch reads $kT$, where $k$ is a
proportionality constant that doesn't depend on $T$, but only on the relative-velocity
between Alice and Bob.

Alice receives the echo when her watch reads $R=k(kT)$, where we have used the same proportionality constant [invoking the principle of relativity... with the usual assumptions of homogeneity and isotropy (as done in Euclidean geometry and Galilean relativity)].

Alice assigns space and time components of the displacement $\vec{OQ}$
as
$$\Delta t_{OQ}= (R+T)/2 \qquad \mbox{half of the sum [the mid-time]}$$
and
$$\Delta x_{OQ}= (R-T)/2 \qquad \mbox{half of the difference [half of the round-trip]}$$

Thus,
$$\Delta t_{OQ}=(k^2+1)T/2\qquad\mbox{and}\qquad \Delta x_{OQ}=(k^2-1)T/2.$$ ​
This can be used to determine the relation between $k$ and the relativity velocity $v_{BwrtA}$.

$$v_{BwrtA}=\frac{\Delta x_{OQ}}{\Delta t_{OQ}}=\frac{k^2-1}{k^2+1}.$$
With a little algebra, $$k=\sqrt{\frac{1+v_{BwrtA}}{1-v_{BwrtA}}}\qquad\mbox{Doppler factor}.$$

Note that $RT=k^2T\ T=(kT)^2=\left(\Delta t_{OQ, Bob}\right)^2$, the elapsed time of $\vec{OQ}$ according to Bob's watch. This suggests that product of radar times $RT$ is an invariant.. it depends only on $\Delta t_{OQ, Bob}$ but not $k$.
For Bob’s radar measurement of $\vec{OQ}$, his radar times are equal (since his reception coincides with his transmission).

One could introduce a third observer

[image: robphy-Bondi-b]

to derive this (and the Lorentz transformations).
See my linked answer above for details.

The bottom line is that $RT$ is an invaraint.

In terms of $t$ and $x$ (as defined above),
we have
$$RT=(\Delta t+\Delta x)(\Delta t-\Delta x)=(\Delta t)^2-(\Delta x)^2.$$
Thus, we generalize the result
as
$$ds^2=dt^2-dx^2.$$